# Python: standrize columns dates while importing an slk file

Tags: python, import, python-import, slk

I'm trying to import an slk file using the `SylkParser()` in python `from sylk_parser`, and I want to standrize all date columns while importing the file.

```
from sylk_parser import SylkParser
SylkParser("path\file.slk")
```

Any thoughts would be great. Thanks.